# Fortran: handling integer values of size: ~700000000000

Tags: integer, fortran, numbers, long-integer

Currently I'm brushing up on my Fortran95 knowledge (don't ask why)...

I'm running in to a problem though. How does one handle large integers, eg. the size of: ~700000000000

INTEGER(KIND=3) cannot hold this number.
If anyone is interested the compiler I have available is Silverfrost FTN95.

I am using the integer to run through a larger set of data.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If one may ask, for what do you need such range ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard solution (since Fortran 95, so I assume your compiler supports it) is to use the [`SELECTED_INT_KIND`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SELECTED_005fINT_005fKIND.html) intrinsic to probe for valid integer kinds (whose values are compiler dependent) and the [`HUGE`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/HUGE.html) intrinsic.

- `SELECTED_INT_KIND (R)` returns the kind type parameter of an integer type that represents all integer values n with −10^R < n < 10^R (and returns -1 if no such type exist).
- `HUGE (K)` returns the largest representable number in integer type of kind K.

For example, on my Mac with an x86_64 processor ([gfortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran) compiler, 64-bit mode), the following program:

```
  print *, selected_int_kind(1)
  print *, selected_int_kind(4)
  print *, selected_int_kind(8)
  print *, selected_int_kind(16)
  print *, selected_int_kind(32)
  print *, selected_int_kind(64)
  print *, huge(0_1)
  print *, huge(0_2)
  print *, huge(0_4)
  print *, huge(0_8)
  print *, huge(0_16)
  end
```

outputs:

```
           1
           2
           4
           8
          16
          -1
  127
  32767
  2147483647
  9223372036854775807
 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
```

which tells me that I'd use an `integer(kind=8)` for your job.

Comment: Kind numbers are NOT portable. Especially given that the 
OP uses `kind=3` and Silverfrost Fortran then `kind=8` is not a good thing. There is no kind 8 in Silverfrost Fortran. At least not in normal settings. One can just directly use `selected_int_kind (12)` in a named constant as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 8):

The portable to declare an integer "index" that will have at least 12 decimal digits is:

```
integer, parameter :: MyLongIntType = selected_int_kind (12)
integer (kind=MyLongIntType) :: index
```

The "kind=" may be omitted.

Using specific values such as 3 is completely non-portable and not recommended.   Some compilers use the type numbers consecutively, others use the number of bytes.    The "selected_int_kind" will return the kind number of the smallest integer kind available to the compiler that can represent that requested number of digits.   If no such type exists, -1 will be returned, and the value will fail when used kind value to declare an integer.

Both gfortran and ifort return a kind for decimal digits input to selected_int_kind up up to 18.   Large values such as 18 will typically select an 8-byte integer with a largest positive value of 9223372036854775807.    This has 19 digits, but if a compiler supports this type but not a longer one, selected_int_kind (19) will be -1, because not all 19 digit integers are representable.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of free [arbitrary-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) libraries available for Fortran which would deal with this problem. [FMLIB](http://myweb.lmu.edu/dmsmith/FMLIB.html) is one. Five or six more alternatives are [linked from this page](http://crd.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using it as a loop control variable, but aren't using the integer directly (which I guess you can't be, as you can't declare an array larger than the largest index representable, right?), then I guess the thing to do is divide that puppy by something like 100000 and nest its loop in another loop that iterates that many times.

Comment: Unfortunately I am.. 

The problem is actually the problem of finding the larges prime factor of a humongous number..

The initial idea is pure bruteforce followed by a smar solution if i ever find one.

The current idea is, the following but for obvious reasons that isen't really possible:

INTEGER :: I=0,J=0,STATE=0,LARGE_DIV=0
long MAX=7100000000000

DO I=2,MAX
  STATE=0
  DO J=2,I
    IF (MOD(I,J)==0) STATE=STATE+1
    IF (STATE>=2) EXIT
  END DO
  IF (STATE >=2) CYCLE
  IF (MOD(MAX,I)==0) LARGE_DIV=I
END DO

WRITE(*,*)LARGE_DIV

Comment: That sounds like a job for a bignum library. Surely there is one around for Fortran...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried INTEGER(KIND=4)?

Comment: Yep.. As far as i can see the highest modification allowed is kind=3..

the compiler error would be:
C:\FTN_Projects\xxxxxx.F95(3) : error 217 - INTEGER(KIND=3) constant out of range

(kind=3) is set by the compiler, supplied argument is kind=4

Answer (score 0):

Our answer to that was to put the value in a double precision variable and do a DINT on it to get rid of any fractional parts.
The results are an integer placed in a double precision variable.
The function DINT is not always available to all FORTRANs. The function is a double precision integer function and this will allow for very large integers (up to 17 digits).