# Fortran 95: Conversion from 8 digit integer to real ends in even real number

Tags: integer, fortran

I am trying for hours to convert an integer, lets say 33333333 to a real using the intrinsic function real(int). What I am ending up with are only the nearest even number, sometimes 33333332 or 33333334. Using integers with less than 8 digits everything works fine. Some numbers with 1 at the beginning of the 8 digits work as well, but from 20000001 on I get a wrong real...

Any suggestions?

My system: ubuntu 14.04 LTS and gcc 4.8.4

Comment: Can you show your code/provide an [mcve]?

Comment: Your real number model cannot represent exactly all integers.  For someone to provide a good explanation it would be helpful to understand your level of knowledge of floating point.

Comment: 33333333 cannot be represented in IEEE 754 single precision floating point.

Comment: thanks for your comments, the example below shows what I mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple program shows the difference of using a single versus a double during the conversion:

```
program compare
    implicit none

    real*8 :: real_8_v
    real*4 :: real_4_v
    integer :: integer_v

    integer_v = 33333333
    real_4_v = real(integer_v, 4)
    real_8_v = real(integer_v, 8)

    write(*, '(E15.8)') real_4_v
    write(*, '(E15.8)') real_8_v
end program compare
```

The result will be:

> 0.33333332E+08 <= single precision
>
> 0.33333333E+08 <= double precision

In IEEE754, that governs this, the "precision" of single precision numbers (32 bits) goes up to 7 digits only. When dealing with double precision numbers (64bits) it goes up to 15 digits.

Comment: okay, thanks for providing a simple example showing my problem. In before I was checking/thinking for the kind/double precision issue, but this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2391837/4267374 made me think that kind 4 is sufficient

Comment: Please restrict yourself to standard conforming code. `real*n` is not valid Fortran and was never part of any ISO Fortran standard.

Comment: @jlokimlin, As the majority (if not all) of fortran compilers accept the *lenght notation, being very easy to find this notation on internet, not being the real concern of this question, not existing a rule in Stack Overflow that we have to "conform" to standard code of any kind and, most important, because I particularly like this specific notation, I'll restrict myself from following your advice. Thank you for your time.